# Confusion on Partial Differentiation

Tags: partial-derivative

If we have $y(x,t)=x^3+t^3$ and $x=t^2$ then $$\frac{\partial y}{\partial s} = \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}$$
Then setting $s=t$ we get $$\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}$$
and we see that $$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}=0$$
which doesn't seem to be correct. I am confused what actually happens here?

Answer (score 0):

Well in your second equality the y on the left in partial y with respect to t refers to the composite function $Y(t) = y(t^2,t)$ while the y to the right of the equality refers to the original function $y(x,t) =x^3 +t^3$ so you can't cancel them .The s is redundant and never should have entered the problem .

Comment: I have heard that when we do a partial derivative, we simply neglect any other variables. So, I wonder how you know that we have to change $y=x^3+t^3$ to $y=t^6+t^3$ on the left before doing the differentiation?

Comment: The composite function must get a different name from the original function .also writing y=y(x,t) is standard practice but is nevertheless an abuse of language that usually causes no difficulty to the initiated but is not strictly speaking correct .  If you had written G(x,t) =$x^3+t^3$in the first place then Y and G are clearly different .

Comment: Also when you write partial of y with respect to t you really mean partial of either Y or G with respect to t and you cant tell from the print which is ,if you see y in both cases :the user has to know which it is from experience ;the advantage of this kind of language abuse (or slang) is the saving of letters ,more important to the thinking then you might think.